# Cut sentences by dots but skip ignore what is inside parenthesis

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-split

I have a piece of code which splits sentences (splits them after a dot, a question mark, or a exclamation mark), but is there a way for code to ignore the part which is in first parenthesis?

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', 'The carrot (Daucus carota subsp. sativus) is a root vegetable. It is red. And it is yummmmy.');
$sentences = preg_split('/(\.|\?|\!)(\s)/', $text);
var_dump($sentences);
```

For example if I have this text

```
The carrot (Daucus carota subsp. sativus) is a root vegetable. It is red. And it is yummmmy.
```

I would need to have these lines, but currently it breaks after `subsp.`

```
The carrot (Daucus carota subsp. sativus) is a root vegetable. 
It is red. 
And it is yummmmy.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `[.?!][^(]*?\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([!?.]\s)`

## Explanation

### First Part

- `[.?!]` means `.` or `?` or `!`
- `[^(]*?` means lazily get everything that's not `(` until

  - `\)` an escaped `)`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Anything this matches is thrown away
- `|` allows for the...

### Second Part

- `([!?.]\s)` An abbreviated version of your original matcher